# Check if value from one dataframe exists in another dataframe and show another column in result

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes:

in df1 i have two columns: keyword and father.
In df2 i have the column caled name.

if any keyword is present in df2 then i want to show the column df['father'].

```
 df1 = pd.DataFrame({'keyword': ['Marc', 'Jake', 'Sam', 'Brad', 'Vinicius', 'Alexandre'],
 
                   'father': ['Minga', 'Maria', 'Cida', 'Neide', 'Carla', 'Nil']})

 df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['Jake', 'John', 'Marc', 'Tony2', 'Bob', 'ALEXANDRE', 'AGNES', 'Bianca']})
```

I want to loop over every row in Df1['name'] and check if each name is somewhere in Df2['IDs'] and show the correspondent row in Df1['father']

Can anyone help me?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.isin()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) to check for column `keyword` value is in column `Name` of `df2`, then use [`.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) to locate the rows with this matching condition, and also select the column `father` to display:

```
df1.loc[df1['keyword'].isin(df2['Name']), 'father']
```

**Result:**

```
0    Minga
1    Maria
Name: father, dtype: object
```